# Can i somewhow shorten this code or change it cuz so many if statements confuse me

Tags: java

```
while (HP > 0 && BOTHP > 0) {
        System.out
                .println("Напишете името на атаката която искате да използвате:");
        String Atack = input.next();

        if (BOTSpeed > Speed) {
            Crit = (Math.random()) * 100;
            if (BOTCHit > Crit) {
                HP = HP - (BOTAtP * 2);
                System.out.println(BOTNAME + "ви нанесе Critical Hit"
                        + (BOTAtP * 2) + " щета ");
            }
            if (BOTCHit < Crit) {
                HP = HP - BOTAtP;
                System.out.println(BOTNAME + "ви нанесе " + BOTAtP
                        + " щета ");
            }

            if (Atack.equals(NAtack)) {
                Crit = (Math.random()) * 100;

                if (CHit > Crit) {
                    BOTHP = BOTHP - (AtP * 2);
                    System.out.println("Вие нанесохте Critical Hit "
                            + (AtP * 2) + " Щета на опонента");
                }
                if (CHit < Crit) {
                    BOTHP = BOTHP - AtP;
                    System.out.println("Вие нанесохте " + AtP
                            + " Щета на опонента");
                }

            }
            if (Atack.equals(SAtack)) {
                Crit = (Math.random()) * 100;
                if (CHit > Crit) {
                    BOTHP = BOTHP - (SSAtack * 2);
                    System.out.println("Вие нанесохте Critical Hit "
                            + (SSAtack * 2) + " Щета на опонента");
                }

                if (CHit < Crit) {
                    BOTHP = BOTHP - SSAtack;
                    System.out.println("Вие нанесохте " + SSAtack
                            + " Щета на опонента");
                }
            }
        }
        if (BOTSpeed < Speed) {
            if (Atack.equals(NAtack)) {
                Crit = (Math.random()) * 100;

                if (CHit > Crit) {
                    BOTHP = BOTHP - (AtP * 2);
                    System.out.println("Вие нанесохте Critical Hit " + AtP
                            * 2 + " Щета на опонента");
                }
                if (CHit < Crit) {
                    BOTHP = BOTHP - AtP;
                    System.out.println("Вие нанесохте " + AtP
                            + " Щета на опонента");
                }
                Crit = (Math.random()) * 100;
                if (BOTCHit > Crit) {

                    HP = HP - (BOTAtP * 2);
                    System.out.println(BOTNAME + "ви нанесе Critical Hit "
                            + BOTAtP * 2 + " щета ");
                }
                if (BOTCHit < Crit) {
                    HP = HP - BOTAtP;
                    System.out.println(BOTNAME + "ви нанесе " + BOTAtP
                            + " щета ");
                }
            }
            if (Atack.equals(SAtack)) {
                Crit = (Math.random()) * 100;
                if (CHit > Crit) {
                    BOTHP = BOTHP - (SSAtack * 2);
                    System.out.println("Вие нанесохте Critical Hit "
                            + (SSAtack * 2) + " Щета на опонента");
                }

                if (CHit < Crit) {
                    BOTHP = BOTHP - SSAtack;
                    System.out.println("Вие нанесохте " + SSAtack
                            + " Щета на опонента");
                }
                Crit = (Math.random()) * 100;
                if (BOTCHit > Crit) {
                    HP = HP - (BOTAtP * 2);
                    System.out.println(BOTNAME + "ви нанесе Critical Hit "
                            + BOTAtP * 2 + " щета ");
                }
                if (BOTCHit < Crit) {
                    HP = HP - BOTAtP;
                    System.out.println(BOTNAME + "ви нанесе " + BOTAtP
                            + " щета ");
                }
            }

        }
```

---

This is the code i try to make a rpg game but im a noob and i can use only the basics if someone know how to shorten this or use something else that wil give the same results This is the code i try to make a rpg game but im a noob and i can use only the basics if someone know how to shorten this or use something else that wil give the same results

Comment: Belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

It won't make it shorter, but it could be a lot less confusing if you pulled some of the bits out into separate functions. The big advantage to doing this is that if you give the functions meaningful names, you'll make the top level function much easier to understand.

It would also make the code easier to test.

Comment: so so many if doesnt make the code ugly?

Comment: It will feel strange at first, but once you get used to it, you will appreciate the benefits.

Answer (score 0):

Use `if-else` when possible, not only `if`, and use `inline if-else`:

```
if (BOTSpeed > Speed) {
    Crit = (Math.random()) * 100;
    HP -= BOTCHit > Crit ? (BOTAtP * 2) : BOTAtP;
    System.out.println(BOTNAME + "ви нанесе " + (BOTCHit > Crit ? "Critical Hit " + (BOTAtP * 2) : BOTAtP) + " щета ");

    if (Atack.equals(NAtack)) {
        Crit = (Math.random()) * 100;
        BOTHP -= CHit > Crit ? (AtP * 2) : AtP;
        System.out.println("Вие нанесохте " (CHit > Crit ? "Critical Hit " + (AtP * 2) : AtP) + " Щета на опонента"
    } else if (Atack.equals(SAtack)) {
        Crit = (Math.random()) * 100;
        BOTHP -= (CHit > Crit) ? (SSAtack * 2) : SSAtack;
        System.out.println("Вие нанесохте " + (CHit > Crit ? "Critical Hit " + (SSAtack * 2) : SSAtack) + " Щета на опонента");
    }
} else {
    // BOTSpeed <= Speed
}
```